# Splitting Columns in R - Just not working

Tags: r

This is R language I'm working in:

I have a large data set and am trying to split columns with different number of values in that column to be split. The separator is "|" and the data looks like this for reasons around not being able to exercise:

```
No transportation
No transportation | Physically Unable | Don't know how
Physically Unable | No transportation
No Money | Don't know how | No Facilities | No free time
```

I'd like to get these into different columns with new columns for each value entered. I'm trying to use this code from dplyr:tidyr:

```
data <- data %>% separate(Exercise_Reasons, 'Exercise_No', paste("Exercise_No", 1:5, sep="|"), extra="drop")
```

Tried this from splitstackshape:

```
cSplit(data,Exercise_Reasons,sep="|")
```

Any help is greatly appreciated as I'm new to R

Comment: this is a text file? just use fread with `sep='|'` and `fill=TRUE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why your separate call doesn't work is because `|` is a regex character, so you need to escape it to be considered as a separator.

This works :

```
 a
                                                                   V1
1                                                   No transportation
2              No transportation | Physically Unable | Don't know how
3                               Physically Unable | No transportation
4            No Money | Don't know how | No Facilities | No free time

tidyr::separate(a, V1, into = letters[1:4], sep = "\\|")
                                  a                   b               c             d
    1             No transportation                <NA>            <NA>          <NA>
    2            No transportation   Physically Unable   Don't know how          <NA>
    3            Physically Unable    No transportation            <NA>          <NA>
    4                     No Money      Don't know how   No Facilities   No free time
```

Comment: Colin, excellent! That worked on the sep ="\\|", looks like it was all about the regex!

Comment: Perfect, glad to hear that :) Can you accept the answer then ? Thanks